# Multiple File Selector jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, plugins

I used MultiFile and it works great, but i can't customize where the files are appeneded. I don't want a file uploader, i tried blueimp and others but what i want is to select mulitple images with preview/remove and send them to server side on form submit.

is there a way to customize multifire or any other plugin to do this that's customizable??

or a way to get values from blue imp on form submit rather than directly upload?

i'm using asp.net mvc 5 just for the record.

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by _customize where the files are appeneded_?

Comment: what i mean in multifile you can't choose where the uploaded files' names show up on the page, so you can't customize the style that much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) which is a very customizable HTML5 upload plugin

Comment: thank you, even though what i originally wanted was a plugin to store uploaded files, and only upload the files on form submit along with the rest of the form elements. But i've gone ahead and used DropZone with direct upload and it's very customizable , so thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could make use of my multi-file [uploader](https://github.com/maslick/aplouder) I have made recently. It's not so customizable as Dropzone, but is small and easy-to-install.

[image]

- enhances the standard HTML `input type="file"` element
- creates an image gallery with thumbnails
- shows size/filename on mouse hover
- on-click image preview (use left/right/esc keys to navigate through the
  gallery)
- support for non-image files
- multiple aploader-s on the same page
- only ~7kB minified
- no extra dependencies (jquery, etc.)

Here's the [demo](http://aplouder.herokuapp.com/).